# Можно ли выбрать для проверки reCaptcha ввод каптчи вместо картинок?

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

Можно ли выбрать для проверки reCaptcha ввод каптчи вместо картинок?
Когда то было так:
[image: Старый вид reCapthca 2]

Сейчас нужно выбирать картинки. В документации пишут о параметре `data-type` но значения он принимает только `image` и `audio`.

Сделать чтобы была обычная каптча реально?

Answer (score 1):

Сейчас это не возможно. Гугл отказался от текстовых капч.